# Simple javascript rollover acting weird with jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm using a simple jquery slideshow and wanted to add a simple jscript rollover since I don't want to mess with the CSS. It rolls over correctly but when you click on it the image that is suppose to be pulled up comes behind the thumbnail images. But when you refresh the screen it behaves correctly. Here is the page with out the rollover but you can see how the thumbnails pull up the images correctly:

http://olbrichdesigns.com/cg_test

Here it is when I added the simple line a jscript to the image to rollover:

http://olbrichdesigns.com/cg_test/index3.html

Here is the simple javascript line.

```
<a href="#2" class="link"><img src="images/spg_puzzle1.jpg" width="221" height="205" alt="" name="puzzle1" onmouseover="this.src='images/spg_puzzle1_hov.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='images/spg_puzzle1.jpg'"></a>
```

Not sure what else to add so you can see without posting insane amounts of code. I suppose if you have knowledge you can take a looksee at the page source of the pages.

Thanks all!

Comment: Can you describe in other words what is wrong in index3.html? I can't immediately notice the broken part.

Comment: Sure thang! If you scroll down to where the 5 images are and mouse over the first one you'll see it goes darker. Which is cool. Then if you click on that image it's suppose to pull up a larger version of that image. But what it does is pull the image up behind all the thumbnails. Then if you refresh the page from there it functions properly. Weird right?

Comment: Also I'm using SlidesJS plugin built for jQuery. I've posted to their group board but haven't heard anything.

Comment: I'd actually like to add one thing I just realized. When you first load the page it's only the first image that does the whole opening the pop up image underneath the thumbnails. Then when you stay on the page and just refresh then it functions like the other rollover thumbnails.

Crazy! And help would be appreciated!